# Typescript generic mapping of predefined shape of arguments to well known return types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to describe type of function that takes predefined forms of input objects and returns well known type of return object.

example

```js
db.queryObject({kind: "user", name: "Bobby"}) => User(...)
db.queryObject({kind: "article", author: ["Bobby"], titleStartsWith: "Introduction to"}) => Article(...)
```

I agree that it would be better to have dedicated methods for each type of object, but how to solve problem in it's current setup?

I followed this approach:

I declared predefined shapes of queries QUser, QArticle, .. and set of return types RUser, RArticle, .. and put them into containers like this

```js
export type Queries = {
  user: QUser
  article: QArticle
}
export type Returns = {
  user: RUser
  article: RArticle
}
```

I tried

```js
let query: (q: Queries[keyof Queries]) => Returns[keyof Returns] = ....
```

Didn't work, because query expects `QUser | QArticle` and returns `RUser| RUser`, I want to have strict QUser => RUser

Then I tried something like

```
type KQ = keyof Query;
let func: <Q extends Queries, K extends KQ>(a: Q[K]) => B[K] = p => {
  if (p === 1) {
    return 11;
  }
};
```

The problem is that return value is `RUser & RArticle`.

**how to solve this?**

Here is simpler version for playing around

```js
type A = {
  a: 1;
  b: 2;
};

type B = {
  a: 11;
  b: 22;
};

type KA = keyof A;

// expect no error
let func: <P extends A, V extends KA>(a: P[V]) => B[V] | null = p => {
  if (p === 1) {
    return 11;
  }
  return null
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common code for all the examples below.

```js
interface QUser { quser: null }
interface QArticle { qarticle: null }
interface RUser { ruser: null }
interface RArticle { rarticle: null }

const qUser: QUser = 0 as any
const qArticle: QArticle = 0 as any
```

The most straight-forward way to do this is to use function overloads. Basically, the idea is to simply list everything:

- if the argument is `QUser`, the result is `RUser`;
- if the argument is `QArticle`, the result is `QArticle`.

```js
function query (q: QUser): RUser
function query (q: QArticle): RArticle
function query (q: any): any {
    // implementation
}
```

When TypeScript looks at function type for a function which has overloads, it ignores the types you've given in the actual function definition (the line with two `any`s in my example). It only looks at overloads, from top to bottom, and searches for a match, using the first-to-match-wins strategy.

Note that your function `query` will still need to do a runtime difference between the types in order to return the correct result. Overloads will only provide you static type information. So it's a good idea to have type guards defined for each of your queries.

```js
function isQUser (x: unknown): x is QUser { return /* test for QUser */ }
function isQArticle (x: unknown): x is QArticle { return /* test for QArticle */ }
```

Now you can use them in your function.

```js
function query (q: QUser): RUser
function query (q: QArticle): RArticle
function query (q: any): any {
    if (isQUser(q)) {
        return /* ... */
    } else if (isQArticle(q)) {
        return /* ... */
    } else {
        console.log(q)
        throw new Error(`Unhandeled type of query.`)
    }
}
```

The only issue with overloads is that each time you add a new query/result interfaces pair, you need to remember to add the overload as well. Note that this shouldn't be a problem since adding a new pair also means you need to change the implementation itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! Something similar was written in documentation, but your explanation with examples worked much better. 
But I still have a couple of questions. 
Is it possible to make an implementation of one of overload optional? If I for example want to proxy calls to underlying model (`db.query() { if isUser(..) User.findOne(..)} else ..`) then I need to have a lot of boilerplate with all overloaded methods. 
Is it possible to extract/describe typedef for such function and somehow filter implementations with `Pick<>` `Omit<>` or something like this?

Comment: Your implementation is completely independent of the types above; you can literally just call an underlying ORM/ODM function in the function body, and call it a day, _if_ you're sure that the overloads are correct. Otherwise, the runtime types won't match the compile time types. You'll need some sort of mapping between your `User` object which holds a method `.findOne` and `QUser` in order to do this properly, but I can't come up with anything now. Will re-try tonight.